# Saving fgets into an array or text file with a time stamp from a while loop

Tags: matlab, text, while-loop, fgets, cell-array

I am using MATLAB to get output from a tracking device for gloves. I basically have:

```
read = fgets(tracker);
tic
k = 1;

while ischar(read)
   read = fgets(tracker);
   toc

   k = k+1;
end
```

I want to take 'read', which is a string, and save it with a time stamp from 'toc' from the while loop and be able to save it in a cell array or text file for post processing. This is for a hand tracker in an experiment.

Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider using a `struct` array (non-scalar `struct`).

Initialize it:

```
tracked = struct('read','','elapsed',[]);
```

Fill it out:

```
tic % then begin reading
% first iteration
k = 1;
tracked(k).read = 'first';
tracked(k).elapsed = toc;
% second iteration
k = 2;
tracked(k).read = 'second';
tracked(k).elapsed = toc;
```

At this point you will have a 1x2 `struct` array, from which you can easily extract data:

```
>> tracked
tracked = 
1x2 struct array with fields:
    read
    elapsed
>> elapsedTimes = [tracked.elapsed]
elapsedTimes =
   1.0e+03 *
    5.8084    5.8212
>> readData = {tracked.read}
readData = 
    'first'    'second'
```

Of course you could also do a `N-by-2` cell array initially, where each row is iteration `k` and the two columns are the elapsed time and read character data.

Comment: Thanks. I had to resort to just an array for easier post-processing purposes.

Comment: @Shagster_84 That's good, do whatever is easiest.  A simple Nx2 cell is pretty simple after all.  However, data extraction from a struct can be very simple too as I've shown.